# Best practice to handle exception in the async call

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

For example, I am using wenclient.DownloadfileAsync to download a file asynchronously.

In the DownloadFileCompleted event handler, I can check if I have any exception or not by using AsyncCompletedEventArgs.Error property.

If I re-throw this exception, however my executable is stopping running immediately.

I am wondering how to handle this kind of exeception? How to pass this exception back to the 
calling thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way *will* be to use C# 5's async support :)

But you can pass the exception back to the calling thread in the same way that you pass the result. If you're using .NET 4, you could use `Task<T>` to allow the original thread to access the successful result *or* the exception. In fact, if they try to access the successful result and there was a failure, the exception will be thrown automatically (wrapped in an `AggregateException`). The caller can check for the failure explicitly too.

If you're not using .NET 4, you can simulate all of this yourself, of course, by writing your own types with the appropriate properties.

Comment: I am using c# 3, any concrete example you can share to pass the result and exception back to the calling thread?

Comment: Wait a minute, there's C# 5? I thought we would be at 4?

Comment: @Bobby: We're at 4 now, but the main feature of 5 was announced at PDC.

Comment: @user496949: Well how are you passing back the result at the moment? Have a look at the `Task<T>` type in terms of its API, and copy the ideas you need.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Oh now I know why the 'will' is italic. Good to know, thanks.

Comment: I am passing a custom object to store the exception and it works.